# Material Design - Wpf - Text Box - Change color

Tags: wpf, xaml, material-design

I'm using Material Design with Wpf application I have `TextBox` based on `MaterialDesignTextBox` static resources

[image]

when the `TextBox` get focus the line color changes automatically to another color  by MaterialDesign:

[image]

How I can control this `TextBox`'s line color? using setter property? what property needs to be changed in the setter? by the way, I change BorderBrush color for textBox but it didn't work

I appretiate any help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `TextFieldAssist.UnderlineBrush`:

```
<TextBox VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        materialDesignNameSpace:HintAssist.Hint="Hey, that's good!"
        Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignTextBox}" materialDesignNameSpace:TextFieldAssist.UnderlineBrush="Pink"/>
```

[image]

[Check out the full `TextBox` material design style for more customization.](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/0bb2445eeb9126368f9cc550b76a692bdcad66ea/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.TextBox.xaml)

Comment: @haydarM.Al-samawe Please accept the answer if this is what you were looking for ^^